# How to extract text only from parent HTML node (excluding child node)?

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest, xml2

I have a code:

```
<div class="activityBody postBody thing">
    <p>
        <a href="/forum/conversation/post/3904-22" rel="post" data-id="3904-22" class="mqPostRef">(22)</a>
        where?
    </p>
</div>
```

I am using this code to extract text:

```
html_nodes(messageNode, xpath=".//p") %>% html_text() %>% paste0(collapse="\n")
```

And getting the result:

```
"(22) where?"
```

But I need only "p" text, excluding text that could be inside "p" in child nodes. I have to get this text:

```
"where"
```

Is there any way to exclude child nodes while I getting text?

Mac OS 10.11.6 (15G31), RSrudio Version 0.99.903, R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will grab all the text from `<p>` children (which means it won't include text from sub-nodes that aren't "text emitters":

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

txt <- '<div class="activityBody postBody thing">
    <p>
        <a href="/forum/conversation/post/3904-22" rel="post" data-id="3904-22" class="mqPostRef">(22)</a>
        where?
    </p>
  <p>
    stays 
    <b>disappears</b>
    <a>disappears</a>
    <span>disappears</span>
    stays
  </p>
</div>'

doc <- read_xml(txt)

html_nodes(doc, xpath="//p") %>% 
  map_chr(~paste0(html_text(html_nodes(., xpath="./text()"), trim=TRUE), collapse=" "))
## [1] "where?"     "stays stays"
```

Unfortunately, that's pretty "lossy" (you lose `<b>`, `<span>`, etc) but this or @Floo0's (also potentially lossy) solution may work sufficiently for you.

If you use the `XML` package you can actually edit nodes (i.e. delete node elements).

Comment: Thank you Bob and Floo0. This is exactly what I was looking for. And I understood now that I most of my problem will be solved once I read more about XPATH functions. Thank again for turning me in right direction.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure the text you want always comes last you can use:

```
doc %>% html_nodes(xpath=".//p/text()[last()]") %>% xml_text(trim = TRUE)
```

Alternatively you can use the following to select all "non empty" trings

```
doc %>% html_nodes(xpath=".//p/text()[normalize-space()]") %>% xml_text(trim = TRUE)
```

For more details on `normalize-space()` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space

3rd option would be to use the `xml2` package directly via:

```
doc %>% xml2::xml_find_chr(xpath="normalize-space(.//p/text())")
```